# Convert HTML to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, request

I have a beautifulsoup object as follows

```
<div class="companyProfileHeader">
<div>Industry<a href="/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::146|equityType::a&lt;eq_market_cap;1">Life Sciences Tools &amp; Services</a></div>
<div>Sector<a href="/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::18|industry::a|equityType::a&lt;eq_market_cap;1">Healthcare</a></div>
<div>Employees<p class="bold">17000</p></div>
<div>Equity Type<p class="bold">ORD</p></div>
</div>
```

I want to convert the above into a Pandas DataFrame as follows

**Expected Output**

```
+--------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|            Industry            |   Sector   | Employees | Equity Type |
+--------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Life Sciences Tools & Services | Healthcare |     17000 | ORD         |
+--------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Suppose that the bs object is named `divlist` I've extracted the text within using `divlist.text` but can't slice it appropriately to achieve above data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken your data as `html` and you can iterate to specific class using `find_all` method and i have used list Comprehension to get text and it is separated by `~` symbol

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
lst=[i.get_text(strip=True,separator="~") for i in soup.find("div",class_="companyProfileHeader").find_all("div")]
final_lst=[i.split("~") for i in lst ]
```

Now you can transform into DataFrame using `final_lst`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(final_lst)
df=df.transpose()
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace = True)
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """<div class="companyProfileHeader">
<div>Industry<a href="/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::146|equityType::a&lt;eq_market_cap;1">Life Sciences Tools &amp; Services</a></div>
<div>Sector<a href="/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::18|industry::a|equityType::a&lt;eq_market_cap;1">Healthcare</a></div>
<div>Employees<p class="bold">17000</p></div>
<div>Equity Type<p class="bold">ORD</p></div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
```

The following would then extract the column and row respectively:

```
column = [i.next for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': ''})]
row = [i.next.next.text for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': ''})]
```

Next, create a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column)
df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=column), ignore_index=True)
```